# display the value of data in svg element using ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, svg

I want to display data from ajax. But I always get error "gigi is not defined" in console.
But When I change the value of variable in  `$("#"+gigi).find("#"+posisi).css({fill: "#333333"});` to be  `$("#P53").find("#C").css({fill: "#333333"});` the element of svg can gets colored when I load the page. So, what wrong with my code?How to write the data value from ajax so its won't get error?

```
function load(){
          $.ajax({
              url:"<?php echo base_url('c_dokter/odontogram/');?>" + id_pasien,
              type:"GET",
              dataType:'json',
              success:function(data){  
                  alert('data sukses ditampilkan');
                  console.log(data);
                  var d = JSON.stringify(data)
                  for (i =0; i< d.length; i++) {
                    if (kondisi.value=="amf") {
                        $("#"+gigi).find("#"+posisi).css({fill: "#333333"});
                  }
                }
              },
              error: function(xhr, status, error) {
              alert(error);
              }
            });
        }
load();
```

Here is the data I want to display

```
 odontogram:
 Array(4)
0: {id_odontogram: "52", id_pasien: "193", gigi: "P53", posisi: "C", kondisi: "amf"}
1: {id_odontogram: "53", id_pasien: "193", gigi: "P61", posisi: "C", kondisi: "amf"}
2: {id_odontogram: "54", id_pasien: "193", gigi: "P21", posisi: "C", kondisi: "amf"}
3: {id_odontogram: "55", id_pasien: "193", gigi: "P55", posisi: "C", kondisi: "ano"}length:
```

Comment: what is `gigi` and where does it get its value`?

Comment: @ildflue update the code

Comment: then you should have something like `var gigi = d[i].gigi` first or use something like `$("#"+ d[i].gigi)`  instead

Comment: @ildflue where should I defined it? inside for loop?

Comment: inside the loop

Comment: `d = JSON.stringify(data)` this should not be right,  it converts the JSON data to a string, I do not think it is what you want. Seems you are going to use the data inside the JSON, so you should convert it into an object / array if it is not

Comment: @ildflue I try to use this $("#"+d[i].gigi).find("#"+d[i].posisi).css({fill: "#333333"}); I dont get error on console but it's not coloring anything of my element

Comment: see my last comment above.

Comment: @ildflue so what should I used to replace JSON.stringify(data) ?

Comment: "The JSON.parse() method parses a JSON string, constructing the JavaScript value or object described by the string. An optional reviver function can be provided to perform a transformation on the resulting object before it is returned."

Comment: It would be better you check the value of data in the console first before you do any conversion. if it is a string, then you do `JSON.parse()` to get an object. If it is an object / array already, you can use it directly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165222/discussion-between-kitcat-and-ild-flue).

Comment: Apparently some of your `id`s are not unique, namely `C` (which you seem to expect finding in the subtrees rooted in the elements referenced by the `gigi` attributes). The code line `if (kondisi.value...` doesn't make sense either, `kondisi` is an attribute of a JS object which you do not reference (should probably be `data[i].kondisi`). As others have pointe out, you probably  do not want `d = JSON.stringify(data)`, in any case use `i < data.length` in the loop condition.